# C# Remote debugging requires exactly the same code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I've a question about the remote debugging in VS2013 using Visual Studio Remote Tools: does the source code I have locally be **exactly** the same as used to build the remote process?
I have a process built with VS2012, made some **minor** changes to the source code to adapt it for VS2013, but when I set a breakpoint in my code I get this error: "the breakpoint failed to bind". Just to recap I use VS2013 and I want to remote debugging a process built with VS2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only about *remote* debugging, it is about debugging in general. 
`PDB` files contain map information between binary code you have and source it was created from. If source was changed, but `PDB` and binaries are not updated, you clearly have a mismatch.

You still can have a breakpoint hit inside a code, but I would strongly encourage you to have always "aligned" sources to the binaries.

Comment: Agreed on that last point. I've been burned by bad deployments and it really affects your ability to properly debug.

Comment: @ragerory: don't forget compiler optimization applied to the code, that you have no control over. So the line hits one see during debug and debugger values, may show totally bogus results, and completely mislead a developer.

Answer (score 2):

Debug>Options, find this option:

[image]

Deselect it, that should allow you to create breakpoints *if* the code is a minor change, depending on how much you've changed, this may or may not work.

You may also need the PDB files in order to debug.